# tensorflow-gpu with anaconda - working properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I installed `tensorflow-gpu` first with `conda` but it couldn't find the dll file, which I realized was due to not installing CUDA and CuDNN. So once I installed it, I tried to set up a session in tensorflow, and got the following output:

```
2018-06-19 19:28:14.869822: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-06-19 19:28:15.902932: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.62
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.30GiB
2018-06-19 19:28:15.909296: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-06-19 19:29:45.384813: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-06-19 19:29:45.397359: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-06-19 19:29:45.401499: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-06-19 19:29:45.406532: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3033 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

It took a while actually to print this. Is there something wrong with my installation, or is this actually a common problem?

Comment: its not a problem. these can be ignored.

Comment: @awd Have you had this problem before? What does it mean? It took about 15-20 seconds to set up the session. Is this normal for tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: this is not a problem. see this [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/566] for disabling info logs. 15-20 seconds for setting up session can be normal depending on you machine performance. I see you have nvidia gtx 1050 which is mostly an entry level gpu.

Comment: @awd ok... When I run a simple Inception retraining (transfer learning) example, it takes 11 min for 4000 steps, but the nvidia-smi shows no activity. Is there a different way of checking for the GPU activity?

Comment: @TanMath you can install MSI Afterburner to see GPU utilization graphs.